# How to make an element as wide as its parent if its position is fixed

Tags: html, css, sass

I want to create a navigation with an image on the left and the navigation bar on the right. The position of the navigation is fixed.
The problem is that the navigation is now wider than the body around it.

How could I make the navigation as wide as the body while having it position fixed?

```css
body {
  margin: 20px 20px 0; }
  body nav {
    top: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 10px 10px 0 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 99;
    height: 80px; }
    body nav .nav__logo {
      width: 180px;
      padding: 10px 0; }
      body nav .nav__logo img {
        width: 100%; }
    body nav .nav__bar {
      display: flex;
      padding-right: 30px;
      padding-left: 0;
      justify-content: flex-end;
      align-items: center;
      flex: 1; }
      body nav .nav__bar li {
        margin: 0 20px; }
      body nav .nav__bar .bar__level1 {
        display: inline-flex; }

/*# sourceMappingURL=style.css.map */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no"/>
    <title>Nav bar problem</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>

<body>
<nav>
    <div class="nav__logo">
        <a href="/" title="Start">
            <img src="">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="nav__bar">
        <ul class="bar__level1">
            <li><p>Start</p></li>
            <li><p>Item1</p></li>
            <li><p>Item2</p></li>
            <li><p>Item3</p></li>
            <li><p>Item4</p></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
<main>

</main>
</body>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/he4c6ur9/

Comment: You set `width:100%` so it as parent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your nav is bigger than the body tag because you set margins on body, of 20px.

If you set left and right position properties to 20px (the same as the body's margin), your nav would be as wide as its parent (the body tag).

https://jsfiddle.net/dbku29oc/

```css
body {
  margin: 20px 20px 0; }
  body nav {
    top: 0;
    left: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 10px 10px 0 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    /*width: 100%;*/
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 99;
    height: 80px; }
    body nav .nav__logo {
      width: 180px;
      padding: 10px 0; }
      body nav .nav__logo img {
        width: 100%; }
    body nav .nav__bar {
      display: flex;
      padding-right: 30px;
      padding-left: 0;
      justify-content: flex-end;
      align-items: center;
      flex: 1; }
      body nav .nav__bar li {
        margin: 0 20px; }
      body nav .nav__bar .bar__level1 {
        display: inline-flex; }

/*# sourceMappingURL=style.css.map */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no"/>
    <title>Nav bar problem</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>

<body>
<nav>
    <div class="nav__logo">
        <a href="/" title="Start">
            <img src="">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="nav__bar">
        <ul class="bar__level1">
            <li><p>Start</p></li>
            <li><p>Item1</p></li>
            <li><p>Item2</p></li>
            <li><p>Item3</p></li>
            <li><p>Item4</p></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
<main>

</main>
</body>
```